# Real-time data standardization / normalization with Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming, normalization, spark-structured-streaming

Standardizing / normalizing data is an essential, if not a crucial, point when it comes to implementing machine learning algorithms. Doing so on a real time manner using Spark structured streaming has been a problem I've been trying to tackle for the past couple of weeks.

Using the `StandardScaler` estimator `((value(i)-mean)  /standard deviation)` on historical data proved to be great, and in my use case it is the best, to get reasonable clustering results, but I'm not sure how to fit `StandardScaler` model with real-time data. Structured streaming does not allow it. Any advice would be highly appreciated!

In other words, how to fit models in Spark structured streaming?

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer for this. It's not possible at the moment to do real time machine learning with Spark structured streaming, inluding normalization; however, for some algorithms making real time predictions is possible if an offline model was built/fitted.

Check:

[JIRA - Add support for Structured Streaming to the ML Pipeline API](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16424)

[Google DOC - Machine Learning on Structured Streaming](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1snh7x7b0dQIlTsJNHLr-IxIFgP43RfRV271YK2qGiFQ/edit)