# Streaming standardization using Spark Structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, left-join, normalization, spark-structured-streaming

It is relatively straight forward to use the [Spark Structured Streaming API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) to perform groupBys and aggregations on streaming data.

For example, I have a streaming data frame, `df` of IOT telemetry data.  I group it by `systemId` and `systemState` and perform aggregations to answer questions like "What is the average and stand deviation of measurement x, for system y in state z?"  This answer again comes in the form of a streaming data frame-- call it `usualDF`.

I would like to consider the following:
"I see system y is in state z and that measurement x has value v.  **Is this high or low**?"

To answer this, I would like use `usualDF` to *standardize* `df`. 
A similar desire was expressed and deemed "not possible" in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074903/real-time-data-standardization-normalization-with-spark-structured-streaming).  Having already implemented streaming normalization on my own in Python using Pandas, I know that **it is possible**-- there just isn't an out-of-the-box function in Spark for it yet.

A nice first step would be to [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#join-operations) the two data frames.  More specifically, we need to take the left outer join of `df` and `usualDF` along columns `systemId` and `systemState`.
The structured streaming API supports left outer joins of streaming data frames, but requires watermarks.  I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;
```

Changing output modes yields:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Stream-stream outer join between two streaming DataFrame/Datasets is not supported without a watermark in the join keys, or a watermark on the nullable side and an appropriate range condition;;
```

`

While `df` has a timestamp and may be watermarked, `usualDF` does not, and I don't see a clear way of endowing it with one.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In the [structured streaming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins), they say:

> As of Spark 2.3, you cannot use other non-map-like operations before joins. Here >are a few examples of what cannot be used.
>
> > Cannot use streaming aggregations before joins.
> >
> > Cannot use mapGroupsWithState and flatMapGroupsWithState in Update mode before joins."

So my "nice first step" is what is unsupported.  I will try to use `mapGroupWithState` to keep track of means and standard deviation as update here with the code if it works.